# Opening score screen from main screen that doesn't extend Activity in ScoreLoop

Tags: android, scoreloop

I am having a bit of trouble with scoreloop. I have most of it set but I am trying to allow the user to open the score screen from main screen but I cant because it wants me to enter into the scoreloop screen by

```
   startActivity(new Intent(this, EntryScreenActivity.class));
```

but I don't extend activity on my main screen so I cant to the above.

The way I get into other screens is as below.
Is there any other way I can get into the scoreloop entry screen?

```
                        if(inBounds(event, 50, 280 + 42, 192, 42)){
                game.setScreen(new HelpScreen(game));
```